# How to deny direct access to files in AJAX directory

Tags: php

I have several pages that call in content via jQuery .ajax. I dont want the content visible on the page so thats why I went with .ajax and not showing/hiding the content. I want to protect the files inside the AJAX directory from being directly accessible through the browser url. I know that PHP headers can be spoofed and dont know if it is better to use an "access" key or try doing it via htaccess.

My question is what is the more reliable method? There is no logged on/non logged user status, and the main pages need to be able to pull in content from the pages in the AJAX directories.

thx

Comment: I have provided a simple php solution that hopefully you might find usefull: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23449295/2883501

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a temporary time-coded session variable. Check the variable in the php output file before echoing the data.

OR, if you don't want to use sessions.. do this:

$key = base64encode(time().'abcd');

in the read file: 
base64decode
explode by abcd
read the time. Allow 5 seconds buffer. If the time falls within 5  seconds of the stamped request. You are legit.

To make it more secure, you can change your encrypting / decrypting mechanism.

Comment: could you explain a little more? I haven't used the base64encode before...is it a standard function?

Answer (score 3):

I would drop this idea because there is no secure way to do it.

Your server will never be able to tell apart a "real" Ajax request from a "faked" one, as every aspect of the request can be forged on client side. An attacker will just have to look into a packet filter to see what requests your page makes. It is trivial to replicate the requests.

Any solution you work out will do nothing but provide a false sense of security. If you have  data you need to keep secret, you will need to employ some more efficient protection like authentication.

Comment: What he's saying is, to the server an Ajax request looks identical to any other request. You can use scripts and encryption methods like @stewie has mentioned and they'll make it slightly more difficult, but any user who knows what he's doing will be able to watch what the browser does when in makes an Ajax request then replicate it.

Comment: @Nathan, I dont need it air tight security, this is mainly to stop the user from viewing these pages directly bc if viewed directly the pages are unstyled and unformatted. However, I can't seem to get anything to work!

Comment: @Dirty but the user will never see what Ajax requests you make, will they? I.e. they will never get hold of the pages you request. Not without a considerable amount of poking around in the source code.

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design: If your only problem is pages unstyled and unformatted, I'd say that you have no worries at all.. A user that recognizes and access to your ajax url probably wont be surprised to see raw data.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have the content be outside the webserver directory, and then have a php script that can validate if the person should see it, and then send it to them.

So, you have `getcontent.php`, and you can look at a cookie, or a token that was given to the javascript page and it uses to do the request, and then it will just fetch the real content, set the mime types and stream it to the user.

This way you can change your logic as to who should have access, without changing any of the rest of your application.

There is no real difference to having `http://someorg.net/myimage.gif` and `http://someorg.net/myscript.php?token=887799&img_id=ddtw88` to the browser, but obviously it will need to work with `GET` so a time limited value is necessary as the user can see reuse it.

Comment: sounds right in theory, i dont have enough knowledge right now to execute this.