# stop direct access (.htaccess) and allow ajax request to subfolder

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to stop direct access to a subdirectories and the php files within subdirectories. I've added the following code below to the .htaccess file within the subdirectories, however now the AJAX request are not working.

How can I stop access to www.example.com/subdir, but allow jQuery load & ajax functions to work?

```
Options -Indexes
order   allow,deny
deny    from all
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

I would put apache directives aside, and -perhaps- focus on a php-based solution:

1. Make sure your file containing the jquery ajax call has a ".php" extension.
   (of course inside that file, all jquery must be contained within `<script>` and `</script>` tags.
2. Inside your jquery function just before the ajax call, type that:

   `<?php $_SESSION["allow"] = "granted" ?>`

   (php tags run even if they are contained in "script" tags)
3. Open your ajax (php) file and at the very top type this:

> ```
> <?php
>  session_start();
>  if((!isset($_SESSION['allow'])) && ($_SESSION['allow']!="granted")){die();}else
>  unset($_SESSION['allow']);
>
>  (...rest of your php code here...)
>
> ?>
> ```

... and you are Done!

P.S. Naturally, you may (or better: should) rename the sessions and give them different or more complex values, but I was just trying to point out the basic idea... Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If your ajax function access some file that is inside that folder, **you can't**. As the AJAX is a requisition sent from the client browser.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

## disable direct access (but allow internal or AJAX requests)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain\.com/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^subdir(/|$) - [F,NC]
```

Replace `www.domain.com` by your own domain name.

Note that this uses `%{HTTP_REFERER}` header to do this blocking and it is possible to manipulate this header value.

Comment: when you say "manipulate this header value" please could you elaborate?

Comment: That means a client can put a custom value in `%{HTTP_REFERER} heade`

Answer (score 0):

I found simplest solution using session.

- project_folder

  - index.php
  - sub_dir

    - db_config.php

suppose you want to restrict direct access of your db_config.php,

you can do like this.
open your index.php from root and add this in first line of your code:

```
$sess = session_start();
$_SESSION["nuclear_weapon_key"] = "lolva";
```

now go to sub_dir -> open db_config.php
add this one the top of the page:

```
$sess = session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['nuclear_weapon_key']) && $_SESSION['nuclear_weapon_key'] === "lolva"){ } else{ echo "LOL"; die();}
```

repeat this for whatever ajax/jquery containing file/s.

it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can use mod_rewrite to restrict access to all bet certain files in a directory. Add this to the `.htaccess` in that directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(jsonp)|(ws)|(ajax)
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
```

Just replace the *jsonp ws ajax* with the name of your files.

Comment: This was prevent all my web pages from loading